# How can i change the default label color black into blue ? i am using react native paper how can i fix this issue.......see the phone label color

Tags: react-native, label, styles, formik, react-native-paper

[image]

How can change the default label color black into blue ? i am using react native paper how can  fix this issue. see the phone label color

Comment: This can be changed using the theme prop, by changing the colors. Not sure of the exact property to change, and not sure if the label color can change on its own without the borders, but the theme is the prop you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use theme property or inline css.

**Theme property**

```
theme={{ colors: { primary: '#808080' } }}
```

**Inline css**

```
         <Text
            selectable={false}
            numberOfLines={1}
            style={[
              styles.label,
              compact && styles.compactLabel,
              uppercase && styles.uppercaseLabel,
              textStyle,
              font,
              labelStyle,
            ]}
          >
            {children}
          </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via `theme prop` like

```
theme={{ colors: { primary: '#BADA55' } }}
```